# Entity Framework bulk inserts causing a select n+1 problem

Tags: sql-server-2005, entity-framework, select

I'm inserting a number of instances of a particular object to a database using the Entity Framework. I have a single object context to which I attach several 'Product' objects. The object I insert has no relationship to any other table in the database. It is purely a standalone entity. I am using the 'EFProf' tool to profile the application.

When I call 'SaveChanges()' to persist my 'Product' entities to SQL Server I am warned by EFProf that I have the 'Select N+1' anti-pattern. I don't see how this is possible since I am simply inserting. My understanding of 'Select N+1' is that it relates to inefficient object retrieval. I am not retrieving anything, only inserting.

When I examine the generated SQL, I see that Entity Framework has generated a select statement on my behalf which returns the Id of the newly inserted object. This select statement is performed for every entity I insert. Could this be the cause of the select N+1 problem? If so, how can I avoid this anti-pattern when inserting a number of entities of the same type in a single call to SaveChanges()?

The generated SQL is below:

```
insert [dbo].[Products]
  ([ProductName],
   [ProductNum],
   [Price],
   [EntryDate],
   [Description],
   [Category],
   [UnitsInStock])
values('TestProduct' /* @0 */,
   0 /* @1 */,
   0 /* @2 */,
   '2011-07-09T17:14:49.00' /* @3 */,
   'Category: Test Products - Name TestProduct' /* @4 */,
   'Test Products' /* @5 */,
   0 /* @6 */)


select [Id]
from   [dbo].[Products]
where  @@ROWCOUNT > 0
       and [Id] = scope_identity()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot avoid that additional select. Once you are using autogenerated Ids in the database and your model is correctly configured for them EF will always create this additional select.

You don't need to bother. Performance of "bulk insert" with EF is so terribly bad that this additional select during each insert means nothing. What should you deal with is the processing itself because EF will create separate roundtrip to the database for each inserted record and that is the problem. If you really want to pass large number of object into database, you want to do it often (it is not one time job) and you expect some performance you should definitely look for other non-EF solution. For example already mentioned `SqlBulkCopy`.

If you just need to insert few instances in some operation you just let it be. That is how EF works.

Comment: Thats a really useful comment thanks. I'm doing some performance testing of NHibernate and the Entity Framework at the moment. This is the first test case I've run and my results for NHibernate are so much faster (even without batching) that I'm starting to wonder what's wrong with my code. I've got my test cases implemented identically as far as I can see. When you say EF performance is "terribly bad" for bulk insert, what are you basing this on? I will need to write up my results so if you have other studies or articles describing this problem that would be extremely useful. Thanks.

Comment: It is easy. Suppose that you create some object with related objects in your applicaton. For example order with 50 order items. If you have feature called command batching (NHibernate has it if correctly used) you will do one roundtrip to the database and it will containt 51 inserts (1 order, 50 items). If you do the same with EF it will sequentially do 51 roundtripts to the database each containing single insert. Roundtrip is the slowest part of almost all operations you can do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for bulk inserts using the Entity Framework.  You can, however, adapt it to use [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).  [This MSDN Article is a good example.](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do a bulk insert, it seems to me that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is useless, since it stores a single scalar value - not a range. I'm going to betray my ignorance of EF, but does it convert this code for to `BULK INSERT` command, or SQLBulkCopy, or something else?

If you're going to do one insert at a time, then checking `@@ROWCOUNT` first instead of putting in the where clause seems to be a better pattern in general:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT [Id]
        FROM [dbo].[Products]
        WHERE [Id] = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Or not even bothering at all, since if the following resultset is empty, you now know what the `@@ROWCOUNT` was:

```
SELECT [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Products]
    WHERE [Id] = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```